# Two derived classes derived from the same base class have different results?

Tags: c++, c++11

Two derived classes having same logic derived from same class but different results.

I have a base class named `account` and two derived classes from `account` class named `savings_account` and `checking_account`. When I make `savings_account` object, everything works fine, but when i make an object of `checking_account` class, it also creates an empty object `account` class. By using overloaded operator <<, `cout << checking_account_object`, it gives me the balance of `checking_account_object`. but when i use `get_balance` method, it gives me the balance of `account_object` (I created `checking_Account_object` but automatically created `account_object`). Similarly works with `deposit` method, it deposits money in `account_object`, not in `checking_account_object`. I have been stuck in this code for 2 days.

Here is my code for `account` class:

```
class account
{
protected:
    string name;
    double balance;
public:
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, account &bank);

    account(){
        name = "unknown";
        balance = 0.00;
    }
    account (const string &person_name, const double &person_balance){
        name = person_name;
        balance = person_balance;
    }
    bool deposit(const double &amount){
        if(amount <= 0)
            return false;
        else{
            balance += amount;
            return true;
        }
    }
    bool withdraw(const double &amount){
        if(amount <= 0 )
            return false;
        else{
            balance -= amount;
            return true;
        }
    }

    double getbalance(){
        return balance;
    }

};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, account &bank){
    out << "The back balance of " << bank.name << " is " << bank.balance << endl;
    return out;
}
```

And Here is my code for `savings_account`:

```
class savings_account : public account
{
protected:
    string name;
    double balance;
    double int_rate;

public:
    savings_account(){
        int_rate = 0;
        name = "unknown";
        balance = 0;
    }
    savings_account(const string &person_name, const double &person_balance, const double peronal_int_rate){
        int_rate = peronal_int_rate;
        name = person_name;
        balance = person_balance;
    }
    bool deposit(double amount){
        amount += (amount*int_rate)/100;
        return account::deposit(amount);
    }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, savings_account &bank);

};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, savings_account &bank){
    out << "The bank balance of " << bank.name << " is " << bank.balance << endl;
    return out;
}
```

and Here is `checing_account` class:

```
class checking_account : public account{
protected:
    string name;
    double balance;
    const double fee = 1.5;

public:
    checking_account(){
        name  = "unknown";
        balance  = 0;
    }
    checking_account(const string &person_name, const double &personal_balance){
        name = person_name;
        balance = personal_balance;
    }
    bool withdraw(double amount){
        amount = amount + fee;
        return account::withdraw(amount);
    }

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, checking_account &bank);
};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, checking_account &bank){
    out << "The name of account is " << bank.name << " and current balance is " << bank.balance << endl;
    return out;
}
```

`main()` function:

```
int main(){
    savings_account savings_account("tanzeel", 2000, 2);
    savings_account.deposit(1000);
    cout << savings_account.getbalance() << endl;
    savings_account.withdraw(100);
    cout << savings_account.getbalance() << endl;
    cout << savings_account;


    checking_account checking_account_object("tanzeel", 100.0);
    checking_account_object.deposit(50);;
    checking_account_object.withdraw(100);
    cout << checking_account_object.getbalance() << endl;
    cout << checking_account_object;

    return 0;
}
```

`Savings_account` is working well. But `checking_account` is not giving me required output.
I expected the output of `checking_account_object` to be

```
48.5
The name of account is tanzeel and current balance is 48.5
```

but the output is 
    -51.5
    The name of account is tanzeel and current balance is 100

Comment: It looks like you are redeclaring `balance` (and `name`) in the derived classes, which hides the name in the base (now you have two `balance` variables) Just stick with the one from the base class.

Comment: O yes It worked !! Thanks